# C - create a bin file of a structs's array inside other struct's array with fwrite

Tags: c, struct, fwrite

I have a struct's array inside other struct's array and I wanna create a binary file which contains this data (only elements no null).

My structs are:

```
struct viaje {
    char identificador[30+1];
    char ciudadDestino[30+1];
    char hotel[30+1];
    int numeroNoches;
    char tipoTransporte[30+1];
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};

struct cliente {
    char dni[30+1];
    char nombre[30+1];
    char apellidos[30+1];
    char direccion[30+1];
    struct viaje viajes[50];
    int totalViajes;
} clientes[20];
```

I am trying next:

```
// For create bin file
for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
    fwrite(clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
    for (j = 0; j < clientes[i].totalViajes; j++) {
        fwrite(clientes[i].viajes[j], sizeof(struct viaje), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
    }
}


// For read bin file
for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
    fread(clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
    for (j = 0; j < clientes[i].totalViajes; j++) {
        fread(clientes[i].viajes[j], sizeof(struct viaje), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
    }
}
```

I have not tryed `fread` yet due to I get two errors in `fwrite`: `error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fwrite'` and `note: expected 'const void *' but argument is of type 'struct cliente'`

Why could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there a a few things going on here. There are some important things to note here.

1. Location of `totalViajes` in `struct cliente`
2. The number of bytes you want to write in fwrite()
3. Resetting the `FILE*` before reading from the file again.

Here is what I used to test what I think you're looking for.

```
struct viaje {
    char identificador[30+1];
    char ciudadDestino[30+1];
    char hotel[30+1];
    int numeroNoches;
    char tipoTransporte[30+1];
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};
struct cliente {
    int totalViajes;
    char dni[30+1];
    char nombre[30+1];
    char apellidos[30+1];
    char direccion[30+1];
    struct viaje viajes[50];
} clientes[20];

int main()
{
    clientes[0].totalViajes = 1;
    clientes[0].viajes[0].numeroNoches = 52;
    int totalClientes = 1;

    FILE* fp_guardarCargarEstado = fopen("myFile.bin", "wb");
    // For create bin file
    for (int i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
        fwrite(&clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente)-(sizeof(struct viaje)*50), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
        for (int j = 0; j < clientes[i].totalViajes; j++) {
            fwrite(&clientes[i].viajes[j], sizeof(struct viaje), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp_guardarCargarEstado);

    // set variables to 0 so you can tell if the read actually does anything
    clientes[0].totalViajes = 0;
    clientes[0].viajes[0].numeroNoches = 0;

    fp_guardarCargarEstado = fopen( "myFile.bin", "rb" );
    // For read bin file
    for (int i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
        fread(&clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente)-(sizeof(struct viaje)*50), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
        for (int j = 0; j < clientes[i].totalViajes; j++) {
            fread(&clientes[i].viajes[j], sizeof(struct viaje), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp_guardarCargarEstado);

    printf("%i\n%i", clientes[0].totalViajes, clientes[0].viajes[0].numeroNoches );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is what I was looking for. I have tested the code and works fine, it is great.

Answer (score 3):

The `fread` and `fwrite` functions take a pointer to a memory location as their first parameter.  You're instead passing an instance of a struct.

You need to pass in the address of this struct using the address-of operator `&`.  Also, there's no need to write the `struct viaje` instances separately, since they are already contained within a `struct cliente`

```
// For create bin file
for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
    fwrite(&clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
}


// For read bin file
for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
    fread(&clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Yes, I have tryed your first code (anidated for) and It creates a extra large file. When I try read it, does not load data. I wanna do a bucle beause I do now want that it saves all data (empty items too), I wanna that only save items which have data

Comment: I mean, an array has empty elements and others with content, I want to only store the elements that have content, not all the array elements

Comment: Note you can `fwrite` and `fread` array of structs on the same machine, but do not consider this a portable solution. It isn't. Different compilers handle padding and alignment in different ways. So if you create a binary file with `fwrite` containing an array of struct, there is no guarantee you can move that file to another computer, recompile your code, and `fread` the values back in.